# Разрезать текстовый файл на части по N строк и символу

Tags: c

запуск через кмд

```
./programma input.txt out.txt log.txt q 3
```

input.txt - входной текстовик, out.txt - текстовик, в котором будет написан результат, log.txt - просто логи, q - символ, до и после которого программа должна "разрезать" строки, 3 - число разрезов.
пусть в input.txt будет строка qwertyqmoqklqqq, символ - q, а число разрезов - 3, тогда результат должен быть

```
q

werty

q

mo

q

klqqq
```

Вот мой код, подскажите, в чем ошибка, и как исправить на рабочее

```
 char* symbol=argv[4], syb;
    char* num=argv[5], N;
    char* filename = argv[1], c;
    FILE* input = fopen(filename, "r+");
    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
      {
          while((c = tolower (fgetc(input)) != EOF))
          {
            if(c == syb)
            {
              putchar(c);
              printf("\n");
            }
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот что говорит компилятор:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O temp.c 
> temp.c: In function ‘main’:
> temp.c:9:11: error: unused variable ‘num’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
>     9 |     char* num=argv[5], N;
>       |           ^~~
> temp.c:8:11: error: unused variable ‘symbol’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
>     8 |     char* symbol=argv[4], syb;
>       |           ^~~~~~
> temp.c:13:18: error: ‘N’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
>    13 |     for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
>       |                ~~^~~~
> temp.c:17:15: error: ‘syb’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
>    17 |             if(c == syb)
>       |               ^
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

В переводе на человеческий:

- переменные `num` и `symbol` не используются;
- для переменных `N` и `syb` не заданы значения.

То есть, программа не пользуется последними двумя параметрами командной строки.

**P.S.** Хорошие вопросы начинаются когда компилятор перестаёт выдавать ошибки.